# DiscordJS v14 | Displaying user input in an embed in a new line with \n

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to use user input in a Discord embed and display it (from a slash command). I am able to get the user input and generate the embed, but the format of the text is not looking good. Specifically, when I set the "Content" of the embed using  `.setDescription(content)`, the text appears in an unappealing format.

I have tried using the `\n` character to create new lines, but it is not working. However, I am able to make text bold using `**`.

Can you help me understand how I can create new lines in the embed's content?

[image: How it looks]

I get the content directly from the user input:

```js
let content = interaction.options.getString("content")
```

Comment: What does your `content` look like? Using `\n` does work for me: https://imgur.com/a/aalTggG

Comment: I get the content directly from the user input:
content = interaction.options.getString("content");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive the `content` using `interaction.options.getString("content")`, that `\n` is no longer the newline character, more like an escaped backslash `"\\"` followed by the letter `"n"`.

It means you can replace those with a newline character:

```js
let content = interaction.options
  .getString('content')
  .replaceAll('\\n', '\n');

// ...
.setDescription(content)
```